# Import images to Drupal 7 using feeds module

Tags: image, drupal, csv, import, drupal-feeds

I have to migrate a custom (non CMS) website to **Drupal 7**. In the current website, some tables have image data that is stored as URL in the db.

I have tried the **Feeds** module with the **Feeds Image Grabber** addon, and also the **Media Feeds** plugin without success (for importing data as nodes).

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to import images from an (external) URL as 'images' into Drupal **from a CSV file**, using the Feeds module (or any other tool that allows both text and images import with mapping)?
2. If not, is there a way to import them from Drupal's images library, also by the use of the Feeds module and/or Media Feeds plugins?

I have tried importing from CSV either by giving the full external URL path or the public://myimage.jpg path without success.

Thanks for any help on that!

Comment: I've used Feeds / Feeds Image Grabber for similar cases several times, usually works well. How did it not work for you? Any errors logged either watchdog or to the php logs?

Comment: It seems that ImageGrabber can only scrape images from a feed's URL. But in my case, I am using a CSV for importing data. We were unable to find a way to import an image (http:// or public://) into a (FIG) image field. When trying to import a one line CSV, here is what I get: Failed to get the file object for public://4245_1.jpg. Created 1 node. The mentioned image definitely is in the public dir. Any advice?

Comment: Never mind. Got it working now. Still this information might be useful to someone else. The issue was that the URL specified in my CSV file had a space before it. Example of non-working CSV: 2012-07-04, Title, Body, "public://image.jpg" and Example of working CSV: 2012-07-04,Title,Body,"public://image.jpg"

Answer (score 5):

you are correct in identifying that the problem is due to the a space. Fyi: you can remove spaces using the tamper plugin for feeds. Just select trim and enter a space in the required field. 
Instead of using `public://image` its also possible the enter the complete url from the site where you get your images, just remember to remove spaces.